# The procedure entry point _Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_ could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: qt, exe

I am trying to create an .exe file from a qt application. The program is running correctly inside the qt creator. I tried to follow the deployment procedure that i find searching the web (for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8qozxqSZQEg)

However, the .exe file can be run successfully only if it is in the same dir as the compiler (i am using mingw73_32). And the error that i am getting back is the following:

The procedure entry point _Z21qRegisterResourceDataiPKhS0_S0_ could not be located in the dynamic link library.

I would like to point that it seems that no dll files are missing.
Can you please help me to solve this issue?
Thanks a lot,

Comment: Did you copy the correct dlls to the target directory?

Comment: As far as i can understand, when you using the "windeployqt.exe", there is no need to copy dlls, because it can "transfer" the dlls which needed in the deployment folder. However, if you think that i should copy dlls, which of them?

Comment: You should at least check that windeployqt.exe copied the correct files. Reasoning: Your code runs in debugger context, but doesn't run once deployed, which means that the contexts differ from each other. Find the difference and the reason for it and you're done. :-)

Comment: You are right, it seems that the Qt5Widgets.dll is missing and it is mandatory for my qt application. Thanks lot for your hint!

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in debugger context, but doesn't run once deployed.

This means that the contexts differ from each other.

Find the difference and the reason for it and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need add to your program the **Qt5Multimedia.dll**, **Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll** and Pluggin (directory) **mediaservice**.
The dll file will depends at your Qt version.

Put them in your program directory.

```
C:\Path\yourFile.exe 
c:\Path\Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll
c:\Path\Qt5MultimediaWidgets.dll 
c:\Path\mediaservice
```

Comment: Remember not to forget to put the Pluggin "mediaservice" directory together in the executable folder.